# BxSlider is working but there is a blank space inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

my bxslider is totally fine but I am not sure why there is a blank space on the right side after image.

First of all, I have imported the jquery library files.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" />
```

Secondly, I put a script for `.bxslider`. The following code are below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        controls:false
    });
});
```

Thirdly, I put a code in HTML something like below:

```
<div id="home-top-left">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="pic1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="pic2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="pic3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="pic4.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Lastly, in CSS. I just put something like this below:

```
.bxslider img {
width:100%;
}
```

The images resolution is 2000x1000. I tried to make the images width become 100% so it won't leave any blank space on the right side.

In conclusion, the sliders are working. But there are a blank space on the right side inside .bxslider. Any ideas? I tried to inspect element and debug, I couldn't figure it out.

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8az4as2g/1/). Thanks!

Comment: Can you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: you didnt add the bxslider plugin to your jsfiddle :(

Comment: @Stefan Hey, I am really appreciate it if you can help me to add bxslider plugin to JSFIDDLE

Comment: press on the left tab: external sources in jsfiddle and then add the bxslider source just like the jquery source: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: [Updated fiddle with bxslider js and css](http://jsfiddle.net/8az4as2g/1/).

Comment: [Unable to replicate](http://jsfiddle.net/aapvuq0c/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem several days ago: On line 32 at the bxslider.css file:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    // DELETE FROM HERE
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc; 
    border:  5px solid #fff; 
    left: -5px;      
    background: #fff;
    // TO HERE

    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
        -ms-transform: translatez(0);
        -o-transform: translatez(0);
        transform: translatez(0);
}
```

Does that fix the problem?
Cheers

Answer (score -2):

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    /*DELETE FROM HERE*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    left: -5px;
    background: #fff;
    /* TO HERE*/
    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/

    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    transform: translatez(0);
}
will fix the issue.
```

Comment: Why "will this fix the issue"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Why it was done : is the question itself.
What is done : is the code it self.